# Less discards first lines, -S does not work

Tags: less

`less` works very strange, discard several top lines, does not update correctly after moving up/down or left/right. Also `-S` does not work. If I move far right, `less` starts to work correctly, but keep failing if move back left.

Here is an example: each line starts with `Line  N` and then English alphabet multiple times. In the beginning I run `most` to show the content of the file.

[image: less]

The same happened in different terminal emulators. But without X running less worked fine. I use Manjaro Linux and bspwm.

What can be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: it looks like less expects your terminal to be a different width than it really is.

Comment: @Jasen Thank you, maybe it's the problem? Do you know what can be the reason for that?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using this command with other long text files? [The `man` page for `less` says](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less)

> Also, less does not have to read the entire input file before starting, so with large input files it starts up faster than text editors like vi (1).

Perhaps the program is intentionally skipping over the first lines in the file, to save on memory? The purpose of this program is to start from the bottom, so it would make sense if it simply didn't load the content at the very beginning.

Comment: Probably not, I tried with different files, this file is something like 200 lines with length 150. Could it be that `less` has access only to extremely small memory?